# CSS - prioritizing css rules

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a projects table with odd and even row coloring for a better view:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

I also have a code that checks if the project is late and if so i color all the project row in red (instead of the usual coloring of the even and odd rows)

Also, each row has a class and the class name depends if the project is late or not.
The classes are:

```
.redBackground {background-color:#CD5C5C;}

.yellowBackground {background-color:#FFFF00;}

.noBackground {}
```

The problem is that no matter which class the row is having, the css of the even-odd rows always "wins" so i never see the red or yellow background.
How i make it work so in case of a late due date, it will show the red and yellow classes and in the regular case it will be odd or even?

Comment: try `.parent .redBackground` or `div.redBackground`. don't use `!important`.

Comment: Why not change the class="redBackground" whenever the project is late for the required element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a selector with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), e.g.

```
table tr.redBackground {background-color:#CD5C5C;}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i needed. Just a question: why tr.red is more specific than tr:nth child?

Comment: @Alex: That by itself is not more specific - class selectors and pseudo-classes are equally specific. Assuming the space between `tr` and `.redBackground` here is a mistake, it is the addition of the `table` selector in front of the `tr` that gives this selector a higher specificity.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks, the space was a mistake, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now! By the way, if i write tr.redBackground without the table, then it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent selector, for your case this should work:

```
tr.redBackground {background-color:#CD5C5C;}

tr.yellowBackground {background-color:#FFFF00;}
```

Or,

```
#parent_div .redBackground {background-color:#CD5C5C;}

#parent_div .yellowBackground {background-color:#FFFF00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this in java script. Assuming you know which rows are for later project.

```
if( project is late ){

  document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "redBackground";

}
```

Keep default class as odd and even and in case of late project change the class. Assuming you don't mind changing class programmatically.

Comment: Obviously he is keeping track of late projects, so place where he checks if project is late, he can add few lines of code

Comment: @TejasPatel I am sure OP is doing the same right now. the problem is the styles related to that class are being overriden. So, OP is asking for higher specificity to override the already present styles.

Comment: I am a "she" :) And of course i know what is late but your solution is exactly what i currently do. I will try the solution above - to specify tr.redBackground

Answer (score -3):

Try using `!important`

```
.redBackground {background-color:#CD5C5C !important;}

.yellowBackground {background-color:#FFFF00 !important;}
```

Comment: Bad, consider writing a more specific selector rather than using `!important`